# Cross-thread operation not valid in static method

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, invalidoperationexception

I have the following code in my WinForms C# app:-

```
private static void displayTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    timer++;
    timeTxtBox.Text = parseTime(timer);
}
```

This is throwing an `InvalidOperationException` with the message, with the details

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'timeBox' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

How would I make this work?

Comment: Hint: It's not because the method is static.  It's because you are calling this method on a different thread.

Comment: You need to invoke the change on a control that only exists in another thread.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private static void displayTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{ 
    timeTxtBox.Invoke(new Action(() => 
    {
    timer++;
    timeTxtBox.Text = parseTime(timer);
    }));
}
```